# aligning vertical text in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rotating, vertical

any suggestions on how I could center the vertical lines in the following table.
Cheers, Batu

```
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c||c||c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{ 2}{|c|}{} & Eingestellt & Gemessen & Berechnet \\ \hline \hline
 & \multicolumn{ 1}{c||}{Messpunkt Nr} & $f_{0}$ & $u(i)$ & $i$ \\ \cline{ 1- 1}\cline{ 3- 5}
 & \multicolumn{ 1}{c||}{} & $Hz$ & $mV$ & $mA$ \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f\textless f^{\prime}$}} & 1 & 400 & 41.9 & 4.19 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 2 & 684 & 79.1 & 7.91 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 3 & 968 & 138 & 13.8 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 4 & 1252 & 252 & 25.2 \\ \hline
$f^{\prime}$ & 5 & 1537.4 & 560.74 & 56.074 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f^{\prime}\textless f\textless f_{0}$}} & 6 & 1574 & 616 & 61,6 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 7 & 1609 & 672 & 67.2 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 8 & 1644 & 725 & 72.5 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 9 & 1679 & 770 & 77 \\ \hline
$f_{0}$ & 10 & 1714 & 793 & 79,3 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f_{0}\textless f\textless f^{\prime \prime}$}} & 11 & 1754 & 787 & 78,7 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 12 & 1794 & 748 & 74.8 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 13 & 1844 & 671 & 67.1 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 14 & 1894 & 590 & 59 \\ \hline
$f^{\prime \prime}$ & 15 & 1912 & 569.74 & 56.974 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f^{\prime \prime}\textless f$}} & 16 & 2912 & 155 & 15,5 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 17 & 3912 & 98.2 & 9.82 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 18 & 4912 & 76.9 & 7.69 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|c|}{} & 19 & 5912 & 64.2 & 6.42 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, readers strongly detest having to crane their necks by 90 degrees just to read some rotated material, especially if it's not truly necessary to rotate the material to begin with. Hence, I would dispense with the rotation part. I would also give the table a much more "open" look, by omitting all vertical rules and by using the macros of the `booktabs` package to replace `\hline` and `\cline`.

Another thing that readers tend to appreciate, in terms of the "look" of a table, is if numbers are aligned on their respective decimal markers, rather than simply displaying them centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,amstext,siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\caption{Zahlen} \label{}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} lc S[table-format=4.1]
                      S[table-format=3.2]
                      S[table-format=2.3] @{}}
\toprule
& \text{Messpunkt Nr}
& {\text{Eingestellt}} 
& {\text{Gemessen}} 
& {\text{Berechnet}} \\ 
& & {f_{0}} & {U(I)} & {I} \\ 
& & \si{\hertz} & \si{\milli\volt} & \si{\milli\ampere} \\ 
\midrule
f< f' & 1 &  400 &  41.9 &  4.19 \\ 
      & 2 &  684 &  79.1 &  7.91 \\ 
      & 3 &  968 & 138   & 13.8  \\ 
      & 4 & 1252 & 252   & 25.2  \\ \addlinespace
f' & 5 & 1537.4 & 560.74 & 56.074\\ 
\addlinespace
f'< f< f_{0} & 6 & 1574 & 616 & 61,6 \\ 
 & 7 & 1609 & 672 & 67.2 \\ 
 & 8 & 1644 & 725 & 72.5 \\ 
 & 9 & 1679 & 770 & 77 \\ \addlinespace
f_{0} & 10 & 1714 & 793 & 79,3 \\ \addlinespace
f_{0}<f<f'' & 11 & 1754 & 787 & 78,7 \\ 
 & 12 & 1794 & 748 & 74.8 \\ 
 & 13 & 1844 & 671 & 67.1 \\ 
 & 14 & 1894 & 590 & 59 \\ \addlinespace
f'' & 15 & 1912 & 569.74 & 56.974 \\ \addlinespace
f''< f & 16 & 2912 & 155 & 15,5 \\ 
 & 17 & 3912 & 98.2 & 9.82 \\ 
 & 18 & 4912 & 76.9 & 7.69 \\ 
 & 19 & 5912 & 64.2 & 6.42 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but as i have stated as a comment above, I have no say in how the fromatting should look like. Thanks for the input anyway. best regards

Comment: @BatuhanGülcan - It would be quite helpful if you posted such an important piece of information in the query itself rather than as a comment below another answer.

Answer (score 2):

The secret is called `multirow`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c||c||c|}
\hline
& Eingestellt & Gemessen & Berechnet \\ \hline \hline
& \multirow{2}{*}{Messpunkt Nr} & $f_{0}$ & $u(i)$ & $i$ \\ \cline{ 1- 1}\cline{ 3- 5}
 & & $Hz$ & $mV$ & $mA$ \\ \hline \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f\textless f^{\prime}$}} & 1 & 400 & 41.9 & 4.19 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 2 & 684 & 79.1 & 7.91 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 3 & 968 & 138 & 13.8 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 4 & 1252 & 252 & 25.2 \\ \hline
$f^{\prime}$ & 5 & 1537.4 & 560.74 & 56.074 \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f^{\prime}\textless f\textless f_{0}$}} & 6 & 1574 & 616 & 61,6 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 7 & 1609 & 672 & 67.2 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 8 & 1644 & 725 & 72.5 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 9 & 1679 & 770 & 77 \\ \hline
$f_{0}$ & 10 & 1714 & 793 & 79,3 \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f_{0}\textless f\textless f^{\prime \prime}$}} & 11 & 1754 & 787 & 78,7 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 12 & 1794 & 748 & 74.8 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 13 & 1844 & 671 & 67.1 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 14 & 1894 & 590 & 59 \\ \hline
$f^{\prime \prime}$ & 15 & 1912 & 569.74 & 56.974 \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f^{\prime \prime}\textless f$}} & 16 & 2912 & 155 & 15,5 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 17 & 3912 & 98.2 & 9.82 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 18 & 4912 & 76.9 & 7.69 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
& 19 & 5912 & 64.2 & 6.42 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would typeset the table more like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \toprule
& Eingestellt & Gemessen & Berechnet \\ 
& Messpunkt Nr. & $f_{0}$ in Hz & $u(i)$ in mV & $i$ in mA \\ 
\midrule
 \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f\textless f^{\prime}$}} & 1 & 400 & 41.9 & 4.19 \\
& 2 & 684 & 79.1 & 7.91 \\
& 3 & 968 & 138 & 13.8 \\
& 4 & 1252 & 252 & 25.2 \\
\midrule
$f^{\prime}$ & 5 & 1537.4 & 560.74 & 56.074 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f^{\prime}\textless f\textless f_{0}$}} & 6 & 1574 & 616 & 61,6 \\
& 7 & 1609 & 672 & 67.2 \\
& 8 & 1644 & 725 & 72.5 \\
& 9 & 1679 & 770 & 77 \\
\midrule
$f_{0}$ & 10 & 1714 & 793 & 79,3 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f_{0}\textless f\textless f^{\prime \prime}$}} & 11 & 1754 & 787 & 78,7 \\
& 12 & 1794 & 748 & 74.8 \\
& 13 & 1844 & 671 & 67.1 \\
& 14 & 1894 & 590 & 59 \\
\midrule
$f^{\prime \prime}$ & 15 & 1912 & 569.74 & 56.974 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f^{\prime \prime}\textless f$}} & 16 & 2912 & 155 & 15,5 \\
& 17 & 3912 & 98.2 & 9.82 \\
& 18 & 4912 & 76.9 & 7.69 \\
& 19 & 5912 & 64.2 & 6.42 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Last version: Additionally one could use `siunitx` to align the numbers better. Note that in this version I also removed the `\textless` commands, as in math mode one should just use `>` or `<` (the 'text' in `\textless` is for text-mode). Also I changed the `^{\prime}` stuff to `'`. Note that I surrounded the `>`s with braces to reduce the spacing.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=2]S[table-format=4.1]S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=2.3]}
  \toprule
  & {Eingestellt} & {Gemessen} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Berechnet} \\ 
  & {Messpunkt Nr.} & {$f_{0}$ in Hz} & {$u(i)$ in mV} & {$i$ in mA} \\ 
\midrule
 \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f'{>}f$}} & 1 & 400 & 41.9 & 4.19 \\
& 2 & 684 & 79.1 & 7.91 \\
& 3 & 968 & 138 & 13.8 \\
& 4 & 1252 & 252 & 25.2 \\
\midrule
$f'$ & 5 & 1537.4 & 560.74 & 56.074 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f_{0}{>}f{>}f'$}} & 6 & 1574 & 616 & 61,6 \\
& 7 & 1609 & 672 & 67.2 \\
& 8 & 1644 & 725 & 72.5 \\
& 9 & 1679 & 770 & 77 \\
\midrule
$f_{0}$ & 10 & 1714 & 793 & 79,3 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f''{>}f{>}f_{0}$}} & 11 & 1754 & 787 & 78,7 \\
& 12 & 1794 & 748 & 74.8 \\
& 13 & 1844 & 671 & 67.1 \\
& 14 & 1894 & 590 & 59 \\
\midrule
$f''$ & 15 & 1912 & 569.74 & 56.974 \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$f{>}f''$}} & 16 & 2912 & 155 & 15,5 \\
& 17 & 3912 & 98.2 & 9.82 \\
& 18 & 4912 & 76.9 & 7.69 \\
& 19 & 5912 & 64.2 & 6.42 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great thanks for the fast reply. i have very strict requirements on how the table has to look like. i like how it looks in the second version ut i have to use the first one. thanks again

Comment: @BatuhanGülcan then still you should not use `\textless` but `<`.

Comment: Relative to what the OP posted, the words "Eingestellt", "Gemessen" and "Berechnet" seem to have gotten shifted to the left. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico seems like I have made a change too much (at the start when I was trying to clean up all those unnecessary `\multicolumn`s). It was not intentional, thanks for pointing out. I won't edit it though.